# How to convert a String array to char array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

We are given an array of Strings and what we require is a char[], i.e, array of all characters in all the Strings
For example:

Input: [i, love, you]

output: [i, l, o, v, e, y, o, u]

First I made an array of arrays.

Then I have found the length of the required char[] array.

I have tried the following so far:

```
char[][] a1 = new char[str.length][];

for(int i =0;i<str.length;i++){
    a1[i]=str[i].toCharArray();
}

int total=0;
for(int i =0;i<str.length;i++){
    total = total + a1[i].length;
}

char[] allchar = new char[total];

for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++){
    //NOW HERE I WANT TO MERGE ALL THE char[] ARRAYS TOGETHER.
//HOW SHOULD I DO THIS?
}
```

Comment: stop doing brainstorming, and write some code. That would rather help.

Comment: `string.toCharArray();` Now stop thinking and code.

Comment: The [`String` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) would be a good place to start.

Comment: Why so rude?
A beginner can ask questions on StackOverflow, can't he?
Sick of all the downvotes I get!

Comment: You can ask a question, but you need to show you've made some effort.  `How can I ... ` is a bad format for StackOverflow questions.  StackOverflow questions should typically be in the following format: `This is what I want to accomplish.  This is what I've tried.  Here is the code that I've actually compiled (or attempted to compile).  I'm having this result.  I'm expecting this result.  What have I done wrong?`  If you want someone else to write the code to turn an array of `String`s into an array of `char`, then you should hire a programmer.

Comment: Now, after you did the edit, have you compiled and tested the code you wrote?  Did it work?  If it didn't work, in what way did it not work?  Did it compile?  Did it crash?  Did it execute but return results that varied from what was expected?

Comment: @AmanArora I'm not trying to be harsh on you, but you're obviously a programming student.  Learning programming isn't about just getting the final answer.  This isn't History or Geography.  What's important is learning how to solve your problems.  Brainstorming is a good place to start, but then you have to actually write some code.  And the next step after writing some code is compiling it and executing it.  From there, it's a cycle.  Brainstorm, write, compile & test, over and over.  You can't skip steps.

Comment: I have been banned from asking further questions. What should I do now?

Comment: Edit your question with specifics on what happened when you tried to compile and run the code you now have in the question.  Also, you can post answers to other questions to get some rep back so you will be able to ask questions again.  Asking for specific help on a chunk of code that you haven't even bothered to compile and run is really poor form for StackOverflow questions.

Comment: Pick up a textbook and read. You should be learning how to do this kind of thing on your own. This is a very basic question and has been answered already elsewhere.

Comment: @AmanArora - Try your code, and if you get any error or so, post the exact error here. If your edited question looks good, I'd vote to reopen this question. I'm ready to help you, if you're ready to help yourself.

Comment: And if you don't get an error, you're just getting results that vary from what you expect, post the actual results and the expected results.

Comment: Tried some more, did the edits

Comment: Your question is still in the form of `How do I ... `.  Your question needs to be in the form of `This is what I've done.  These are the results I get when I try to compile and execute this code, but THESE are the results I want to get.  What's wrong?`

Comment: As you can see, whatever I do, the thing comes down to the question "How do I?. . ."

Comment: This is highly demotivating and upsetting, though.

Comment: And StackOverflow isn't really an appropriate place for asking `How do I...` questions.  StackOverflow is for `I've attempted doing this.  But my results are incorrect.`  If that ends with `How do I fix it?` that's fine.  But you're not asking for help fixing a problem that you've attempted to solve.  You're asking for the solution to the problem.  You haven't even made a guess as to how you'd solve the problem.

Comment: Try literally ANYTHING.  Compile and execute the code.  See if it works.  If it doesn't work, come back and say "I tried this and expected these results but got these other results instead, but it didn't work.  What have I done wrong?"

Comment: @AmanArora- Just because you stuck with this question(tried to code yourself, edited the question, and asked a specific problem here) instead of creating a new question(though I guess you said you were banned from asking furthur question), that a mod reopened your question once again. Always try to show some effort, and then expect some help. Without any effort from your side, there won't be any help from the community.

Answer (score 8):

```
String[] sArray = {"i", "love", "you"};
    String s = "";
    for (String n:sArray)
        s+= n;
    char[] c = s.toCharArray();
```

Comment: stringbuilder would be more efficient for longer input.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that like this

```
char[] allchar = new char[total]; // Your code till here is proper

// Copying the contents of the 2d array to a new 1d array
int counter = 0; // Counter as the index of your allChar array
for (int i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) { 
    for (int j = 0; j < a1[i].length; j++) { // nested for loop - typical 2d array format
        allchar[counter++] = a1[i][j]; // copying it to the new array
    }
}
```

Comment: Finally, Thank you R.J!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the following method..

```
    public void converter(String[] stringArray) {


    char[] charsInArray = new char[500];    //set size of char array    
    int counterChars = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) { 

        int counterLetters = 0; //declare counter for for amount of letters in each string in the array 

        for (int j = 0; j < stringArray[i].length(); j++) { 


            // below pretty self explanatory extracting individual strings and a
            charsInArray[counterChars] = stringArray[i].charAt(counterLetters);

            counterLetters++;
            counterChars++;
        }
    }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String [] s = new String[]{"i", "love", "you"};

int length = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {        
    for (int j = 0; j < s[i].length(); j++) {
        length++;
    }
}

char [] c = new char[length];
int k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {        
    for (int j = 0; j < s[i].length(); j++) {
        c[k] = s[i].charAt(j);
        k++;
    }
}
for (int j = 0; j < c.length; j++) {
    System.out.print("char is: " + c[j]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 we can use streams.

```
public char[] convert(String[] words) {
    return Arrays.stream(words)
            .collect(Collectors.joining())
            .toCharArray();
}
```

Here we created a stream from an array using
[`Array.stream(T[] array)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#stream(T%5B%5D)) where T is the type of the array elements.
Than we obtain a string using [`Collectors.joining()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining()). Finally we get a char array using the String's [`toCharArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()) method.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String sentence="Gokul Krishna is class leader";
    String[] array=sentence.split("\\s");
    int counter;
    //String word = new String();
    for(String word:array)
    {
        counter=0;
        char[] wordArray=word.toCharArray();
        for(int i=0;i<wordArray.length;i++)
        {
            counter++;
        }
        System.out.println(word+ " :" +counter);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Code only" answers do little to help a novice understand. Please consider explaining your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
public char[] convert(String[] arr) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String s : arr) {
        sb.append(s);
    }
    return sb.toString().toCharArray();
}
```