# How to convert a String array to a CharSequence?

Tags: java, android

I need to display a dialogue with a list of colors to choose from. I found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16389581/android-create-a-popup-that-has-multiple-selection-options).

```
CharSequence colors[] = new CharSequence[] {"red", "green", "blue", "black"};

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Pick a color");
builder.setItems(colors, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // the user clicked on colors[which]
    }
});
builder.show();
```

I already have a String array of colors. How can I convert it to a CharSequence? I was thinking to use type casting

```
CharSequence colors[] = (CharSequence) mStringArray;
```

But this route does not work

Comment: Brackets?
CharSequence colors[] = (CharSequence[]) mStringArray;

Comment: Did you tried this code in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19594587/how-to-convert-a-string-array-to-char-array-in-java

Comment: A `String` is a `CharSequence`. A `String[]` is a `CharSequence[]`. Just pass your `String[]` in `setItems()`.

Comment: A `String` is already a `CharSequence`. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? (BTW, the cast should be `(CharSequence[]) mStringArray`)

Comment: @TedHopp You solved my problem, you can post your comment as answer and I will check-mark you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `String` is already a `CharSequence` and since arrays are [covariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) in Java, a `String[]` is already a `CharSequence[]`. You probably don't need a cast at all, but if you use one it should be `(CharSequence[]) mStringArray`.